# Ordering by created-at with next and previous post links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

From other questions and answers on here, I can see that to create 'Next' and 'Previous' links you can do this:

```
def previous_post
  self.class.first(:conditions => ["title < ?", title], :order => "title desc")
end

def next_post
  self.class.first(:conditions => ["title > ?", title], :order => "title asc")
end
```

which will order by title if they are unique. I don't quite understand the conditions syntax and was wondering if someone could explain that.

What if I want to order by created_at date, I could change the order to created_at desc and created_at asc, but then what would my conditions be?

Comment: That's just the way you did active record queries in rails 2.  They're using it because they're ordering by the title.  Your conditions would be `["created_at < ?", created_at]` for previous and `["created_at > ?", created_at]` for the next post

Comment: would there be a more efficient way to do this in Rails 4? or is that syntax ok? Also what is this saying ["created_at < ?", created_at], just so i can get it right in my head

Answer (score 1):

If you're on rails 4 you'd do:

```
def previous_post
  self.class.where("created_at < ?", created_at).order(created_at: :desc).first
end

def next_post
  self.class.where("created_at > ?", created_at).order(created_at: :asc).first
end
```

Comment: thanks, though im not sure this is doing what i want. if you go to the latest post http://myblogview.herokuapp.com/posts/use-an-image-as-your-label-with-radio-buttons, then when you click previous post it takes you right back to the very first post that was created, as opposed the the post the day before... I can see why its doing this as we are using .first, but what if i dont want to do that?thanks

Comment: @Richlewis then don't use created_at, have a date field you set on blog posts and use that

Comment: i havent got one, i use a helper to convert the created_at date :(

Comment: I don't believe you, are you using `updated_at`? Where do the dates at the top of the blog post go?

Comment: yes there is an updated_at column, though im wondering why created at behaves this way, i use this helper def date_output(date)  date.strftime("%e %B %Y") if date end and then pass through the created-at date, should i not do this in the view?

Comment: If you're using the created_at date in that then the above code will work.

Comment: so just to check... if you go to the link provided which starts at the most recent post, clicking previous post should take you all the way back to the oldest post ? is that the behavior you expect?

Comment: No, but that isn't what the code I posted does.  Previous post gets the ones where created_at is less than the current post's created at i.e. created earlier. Then orders it by created_at descending.  So the most recent post is first and gets that.  Next post does the opposite.  Either you've made an error somewhere or have a scope set up in which case you'd need to use `.unscoped`

Comment: thanks for the explanation, that helps clear up what the condition part was doing... how do i use .unscoped?

Comment: `self.class.unscoped.where("created_at < ?", created_at).order(created_at: :desc).first`